# CSS - website overlay when page is loaded

Tags: php, css, html

Im setting up a website with a different navigation structure compared to whats traditional, and i want to add a overlay on top of the site which is loaded when the user enters the site the first time.

The overlay should be fullscreen, black "opacity=50", and im going to add simple text about how to use the website. It should also go away when klicking

Im a web designer, and i have limited knowledge in coding. (some css/html/php)

Is there a simple way to add a class for this?

Thanks for feedback

Comment: Yea, nice idea, but did you try it?

Comment: Show us what you've tried already.

Comment: Yes, there is a simple way. Thanks for asking ;)

Comment: Careful guys he might have **Mjölnir**

Comment: I like this website feature.  I shall have another!

Comment: you all guys are making fun of him, rather than writing one line solution.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough
HTML

```
<div id='overlay'>
  <div id='contents'>...
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#overlay {
  background-image : url('images/overlay.png');
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#contents {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

I use an image from the overlay because any opacity setting is carried through to the contents area and no javascript is required or ever needs to be used for this type of content.

Answer (score 1):

Google it! It's not hard. A *very* quick Google search brought me [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/append-site-overlay-div/):

```
$(function() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
    $("#overlay").height(docHeight).css({
        'opacity' : 0.4,
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'top' : 0,
        'left' : 0,
        'background-color' : 'black',
        'width' : '100%',
        'z-index' : 5000
    });
});
```

To close the overlay by clicking anywhere you can do the following:

```
$('#overlay').click(function (e) {
    this.remove();
});
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ssj3p/) to demonstrate.

Comment: what if javascript is not enabled?

Comment: That simply puts an overlay on the screen but does not allow for the informational text that the OP wants on the page.

Comment: Add the text to the overlay div. I'm trying to point them in the right direction, not do it for them.

Comment: hi there.. thanks for feedback and for pushing me in the right direction:).. does this go in the html, or in the css?

Comment: Just add it to the JavaScript section of the page.

Comment: wow, that worked nicely.. is there also a code to remove the overlay by clicking anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<style>
#displaybox {
    z-index: 10000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /*older IE*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50); /* IE */
    -moz-opacity: .50; /*older Mozilla*/
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;   /*older Safari*/
    opacity: 0.5;   /*supported by current Mozilla, Safari, and Opera*/
    background-color:#000000;
    position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
<script>
function clicker(){
    var thediv=document.getElementById('displaybox');
    if(thediv.style.display == "none"){
        thediv.style.display = "";
        thediv.innerHTML = "<table width='100%' height='100%'><tr><td align='center' valign='middle' width='100%' height='100%'><object classid='clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B' codebase='http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab' width='640' height='500'><param name='src' value='http://cowcast.creativecow.net/after_effects/episodes/Shape_Tips_1_POD.mp4'><param name='bgcolor' value='#000000'><embed src='http://cowcast.creativecow.net/after_effects/episodes/Shape_Tips_1_POD.mp4' autoplay='true' pluginspage='http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/' height='500' width='640' bgcolor='#000000'></embed></object><br><br><a href='#' onclick='return clicker();'>CLOSE WINDOW</a></td></tr></table>";
    }else{
        thediv.style.display = "none";
        thediv.innerHTML = '';
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="displaybox" style="display: none;"></div>
<a href='#' onclick='return clicker();'>Open Window</a>
</body>
```

In this site http://library.creativecow.net/articles/chaffin_abraham/full-page-overlay.php